# Bug?: Removing inappropriate tag doesn't remove question from filtered list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Because of my limited areas of competence (I hesitate to claim 'expertise'), I filter the questions I view on SO to those areas. Today, I spotted a question that was improperly tagged, and edited the question to remove the improper tag.

This removal left the question with no tags for my areas of competence (and therefore no tags that were in my filter). When I refreshed the page, however, the question continued to appear, **with only the remaining tags, none of which were in my filter**.

Is this considered correct behavior? If so, why?

Comment: Tag pages use a cache to track what posts appear on the page, and the post snippets themselves are also pulled from a cache. When you make changes to the post tags it takes a short while to update the relevant caches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

(spoiler alert, yes, you should)

Comment: I don't see how it can be a caching issue, because the improperly tagged question is showing up _without the improper tag that I removed_.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The list of quesitons for your tag list is what's cached, not the list of tags for that question.  You just need to be patient, the cache time is not very long.

Comment: OK, that appears to have in fact been the issue; I think that perhaps your comment above should have been [part of] the answer, especially since my job's mommyware blocks 'humor' sites.